# Changing cursor shape in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

Is there any way to change the cursor shape within Windows Subsystem for Linux terminal? I'd like my cursor to reflect the state I'm in in vim or vi-mode.

In Git Bash for example I can use `echo -ne "\e[2 q"` and `echo -ne "\e[6 q"` to switch between block and line cursor. These don't seem to have any effect in WSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using Bash through the default terminal window that comes with WLS.

If so then you will need to replace that terminal as it is not capable of understanding the special escape sequences. The only way I know to do this is to install a GUI such as Unity or XFCE4 and then install your preferred terminal emulator. This [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/637) will tell you how to do that.

This is probably overkill just for changing the cursor but it does have other advantages too, with a GUI installed you can now run many other Linux apps, not all work 100% but most will work fine, you can even set up a unified desktop with a Linux task bar and a windows task bar all on one screen.

Comment: Also, 1.5 years later, using the current version of WSL, the cursor shape can now be changed when run e.g. inside ConEmu.

Answer (score 6):

Since now there is an option for this, I would like to share it here

In settings.json of windows terminal you can set

```
        "cursorColor" : "#FFFFFF",
        "cursorShape": "filledBox",
```

inside the "profiles"

Taken from https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/terminal/custom-terminal-gallery/retro-command-prompt

Comment: settings.json may be found in [drive]:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json

Comment: And a simpler solution may be found at https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-cursor-shape-for-a-profile-in-windows-terminal

Answer (score 5):

Under Settings -> Profiles (either in "Defaults" for all, or pick a specific profile) -> Additional Settings -> Appearance -> Cursor -> Cursor Shape. Set to "filled box" or whatever you prefer.

(I'm guessing this was not available in GUI when other people answered this, e.g. an answer from two years ago says you have to set it in JSON. You can now change it in the GUI, at least as of Windows 11.)